# How to add person image in image frame only?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Any one know how to add person image in frame in swift. I have tried here its video. Right now i did add frame imageview and above i have added person imageview. but i don't know how to add person imageview only in blur part only

https://drive.google.com/open?id=18nchB2wh5hqjlcGqxHrsDbtpe9VkEoKd

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imgFrame : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgPerson : UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView : UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.imgPerson.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan))
    self.imgPerson.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0//maximum zoom scale you want
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0

    scrollView.delegate = self

}

@IBAction func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {

        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        // note: 'view' is optional and need to be unwrapped
        gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}
}

extension ViewController : UIScrollViewDelegate {
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imgPerson
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show a picture example of what you are trying to achieve? I’m not certain what it is you’re trying to do. Thanks 

Comment: @Fogmeister I was trying set image on frame(New Year Frame,Childer day frame) but i don't know how to do it. But now i have successfully did my job. Thanks for comment.